# Data Structure in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there a way to read the SSTable in Cassandra? I see from the documentation that sstabledump is an enterprise version, Is it possible to get the trial version of sstabledump?

Or is there a way to read the SSTable using the existing utilities in Cassandra/bin folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sstabledump is also available in apache cassandra.

It can be found in tools/bin directory in cassandra 3.x

**Note:** sstable2json was replaced by sstabledump in 3.0

Comment: Hey noticed you are Active in Cassandra, Could you please try to respond this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709008/aggregation-in-cassandra-across-partitions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710070/sum-aggregation-for-each-columns-in-cassandra

Answer (score 3):

You can use sstable2json for that.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTable2Json.html

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump

Comment: Hey Simon, Could you please try to answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709008/aggregation-in-cassandra-across-partitions It would be Great. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710070/sum-aggregation-for-each-columns-in-cassandra

Comment: @Harry You should probably slow down with your questions for a bit. At least until you feel you've gotten an answer on the previous one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628950/initial-token-is-cassandra-is-not-working-as-expected