# Is there a limit to size of array in SELECT ~ WHERE IN (huge_array)?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a terrible query I'm using with Cassandra, and wondering how many items can be in the `WHERE IN (array)` clause?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_keyspace.my_table
WHERE uuid IN (
  94e60226-da89-44ab-8255-716e1a2e9e98,
  92c3e7b1-d5bd-45f4-ae1d-b5e2033bb5c2,
  3b3f4335-e11c-4695-805b-453ffdfb664d,
  9134fa1e-a199-4cd9-b45c-0243c6e7c0b2,
  efa99981-ded0-4462-ba2e-73f7e08467ab,
  ...
);
```

I've successfully queried up to 1000 items, but I'm leary of scaling it further, and have been breaking my queries up into batches. Does anyone know if there is an upper limit?

I didn't find anything in the [Cassandra docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#where-clause).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709008/aggregation-in-cassandra-across-partitions/47712662#47712662 as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there a hard or soft limit about the number of items in the IN clause, I don't think there is one.

But in general, select IN ... doesn't scale well while fetching data from many partitions, because, as each partition might be in a different node, it creates many inter node communication, then it can also put pressure on the coordinator node while merging the result.

It is classified as an antipatter 
Here are some links to the documentation :

https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddaccql/doc/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__selectInNot

An interresting article about the subject : 
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

I hope that this helps !