# Sum aggregation for each columns in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Data model like below,

```
CREATE TABLE appstat.nodedata (
    nodeip text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    flashmode text,
    physicalusage int,
    readbw int,
    readiops int,
    totalcapacity int,
    writebw int,
    writeiops int,
    writelatency int,
    PRIMARY KEY (nodeip, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
```

where, nodeip - primary key and timestamp - clustering key (Sorted by descinding oder to get the latest),

Sample data in this table,

```
SELECT * from nodedata WHERE nodeip = '172.30.56.60' LIMIT 2;

 nodeip       | timestamp                       | flashmode | physicalusage | readbw | readiops | totalcapacity | writebw | writeiops | writelatency
--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------+----------+---------------+---------+-----------+--------------
 172.30.56.60 | 2017-12-08 06:13:07.161000+0000 |       yes |            34 |     57 |       19 |            27 |       8 |        89 |           57
 172.30.56.60 | 2017-12-08 06:12:07.161000+0000 |       yes |            70 |      6 |       43 |            88 |      79 |        83 |           89
```

This is properly available and whenever I need to get the statistics I am able to get the data using the partition key like below,

(The above logic seems similar to my previous question : [Aggregation in Cassandra across partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709008/aggregation-in-cassandra-across-partitions)) **but expectation is different**,

I have value for each column (like readbw, latency etc.,) populated for every one minute in all the 4 nodes.

Now, If I need to get the max value for a column (Example : readbw), It is possible using the following query,

```
SELECT max(readbw) FROM nodedata WHERE nodeip IN ('172.30.56.60','172.30.56.61','172.30.56.60','172.30.56.63') AND timestamp < 1512652272989 AND timestamp > 1512537899000;
```

1) **First question** : Is there a way to perform **max** aggregation on all nodes of a column (readbw) without using IN query?

2) **Second question** : Is there a way in Cassandra, whenever I insert the data in Node 1, Node 2, Node 3 and Node 4.
It needs to be aggregated and stored in another table. So that I will collect the aggregated value of each column from the aggregated table.

If any of my point is not clear, please let me know.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: "All nodes" in your case is it constant (literally all nodes), or variable (like,  nodes comprising some cluster, and the list of nodes could change)?

Comment: List of nodes will vary. Is it gonna make a difference irrespective of Replication Factor?

Comment: This was related to 1st question - the list inside `IN` it's constant, or not - I thought about how the schema could be adapted to it.

Comment: IN query usage will involve all the Cassandra nodes (i.e) If there are 4 nodes in the cluster, then the IN query will involve all the four nodes like '172.30.56.60','172.30.56.61','172.30.56.60','172.30.56.63'

Comment: Each node will have its own statistics with the partition key as its nodeIp and Clustering key as its timestamp for sorting. NOTE : Since the aggregation needs to be performed across the nodes for each column I don't have an easy way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you are dse Cassandra you can enable spark and write the aggregation queries

Comment: Thanks, But I can't add the apache spark to it, Do you think that data model I used is a right choice?

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer. In your question you should define restrictions to query speed. Readers do not know whether you're trying to show this in real time, or is it more for analytical purposes. It's also not clear on how much data you're operating and the answers might depend on that.

Firstly decide whether you want to do aggregation on read or write. This largely depends on your read/write patterns.

1) First question: (aggregation on read)
The short answer is no - it's not possible. If you want to use Cassandra for this, the best approach would be doing aggregation in your application by reading each nodeip with timestamp restriction. That would be slow. But Cassandra aggregations are also potentially slow. This warning exists for a reason:

```
Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key
```

I found C++ Cassandra driver to be the fastest option, if you're into that.

If your data size allows, I'd look into using other databases. Regular old MySQL or Postgres will do the job just fine, unless you have terabytes of data. There's also influx DB if you want a more exotic one. But I'm getting off-topic here.

2) Second question: (aggregation on write)
That's the approach I've been using for a while. Whenever I need some aggregations, I would do them in memory (redis) and then flush to Cassandra. Remember, Cassandra is super efficient at writing data, don't be afraid to create some extra tables for your aggregations. I can't say exactly how to do this for your data, as it all depends on your requirements. It doesn't seem feasible to provide results for arbitrary timestamp intervals when aggregating on write.

Just don't try to put large sets of data into a single partition. You're better of with traditional SQL databases then.

Comment: Don't divert the topic please, Anyways to answer your question, Data size will be every minute one stat entry will be there. We will hold the most recent 3 months data. Now can you throw your points in Cassandra's point of view?

Comment: Look, I'm just trying to figure out if you're using the right tool for the job. Cassandra is good for some things, but not others. Then also you have not answered any of my questions:

how fast do you expect queries to complete?
how many rows would you have in total?

Comment: Sorry I answered that in another question, Missed here, It will be one entry for every minute. So one row for every minute

Comment: Also Do you think that Data model I used is a right choice?